# jQuery filtering by post

Tags: jquery, filter, filtering, taxonomy

I have an archive page that shows custom posts, each of which has a `div` that shows the post's taxonomy terms (custom categories 'jobtype') in a div like so:

```
<div class="hidden tags category1 category2 cat3 etc..."></div>
```

Then I have a form with checkboxes each with a value that corresponds to some possible categories that the posts can have:

```
<input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="academia" />Academia<br />
<input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="adminassistant" />Admin/Assistant<br />
<input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="communicationsmarketing" />Communications/Marketing<br />
<input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="development" />Development<br />
```

I want to use jQuery to filter (read: `$('.postclass').hide();`) the current posts based on the checkboxes selected.  Currently I'm using the following jQuery code:

```
var $checkboxes;

function storecat() {         
    var tags = $checkboxes.map(function() {
        if(this.checked) return this.value;
    }).get().join(' ');
    $('#selected-interests').html(tags); 
}

$(function() {
    $checkboxes = $('.filterbox:checkbox').change(storecat);
});

$('#filtersubmit').click(){

}
```

And this is a dulled example of what a post entry looks like on the category page:

```
<div class="post_entry">
    <div class="post-thumb"></div>
    <h4 class="post-title"><a href="#" title="Title">Title</a></h4>
<div class="post-meta">
    <p class="post_meta_organization">Job Organization</p>
        <p class="post_meta_location">City, State</p>
        <p class="post_meta_url">Website: <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden tags early-career internship other web-developmentit"></div>
    <p class="post_excerpt">Post Content Here</p>
</div>
```

I think I need to do a `$('.post_entry').each();` to check against the var `tags`, but I'm entirely unsure of where to begin.  What I think I need is to create an array of tags (right now they're creating a list?), and create an array of classes in the `<div class="hidden tags..."></div>`

I want it to hide posts that don't have any relevant tags, but only show posts that have all the tags selected.  If anyone can help out with my `.each()` function it would be highly appreciated.

If you want to check out more of the layout, go to http://www.cirkut.net/wp/libertyguide/jobs

If any more info is needed, please ask.

**SUB-QUESTION:**

How would make all posts show if NO inputs are selected?  I didn't post this as a new question because I find this highly relevant to this question.

If I have a submit button `<input id="filter_submit" value="FIND" />`

and I alter the jQuery to be

```
$('#filter_submit').click( function() {
    $('.tags').parent().hide();
    $('input:checked').each( function(i) {
    $('div.' + $(this).val()).parent().show();
});
```

When I click the submit button, all the posts hide.  Any help?

Comment: Hi Josh, just so I understand the subquestion better, in http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/3/, when the page loads, all posts are shown. When you select inputs, then unselect them all, all the posts are shown again. What should be different to make it work for the subquestion?

Comment: I updated my sub-question with more info.  I changed your fiddle around to http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/6/, because I want to show ONLY the posts with values that are selected.  NOW when everything is unchecked after the first run, they are all gone.

Comment: Hi Josh, I edited my answer below to show all posts when no inputs are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/1/

```
$('input').click( function() {
    $('.tags').hide();
    $('input:checked').each( function() {
        $('div.' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

It's currently set to only show the items that are selected, but you could flip it to hide the items that are selected instead (i.e., http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/2/).

**EDIT:**

It looks like you might be hiding the container div of `post-meta`, in which case you could do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/3/, which hides the parent container

```
$('input').click( function() {
    $('.tags').parent().show();
    $('input:checked').each( function() {
        $('div.' + $(this).val()).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

**SUBQUESTION EDIT:**

Modified to 're-show' all posts when all checkboxes are cleared:
http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/8/

```
$('input').click( function() {
    $('.tags').parent().hide();
    $('input:checked').each( function() {
        $('div.' + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
    if (!$('input:checked').length) $('.tags').parent().show();
});
```

Comment: @Josh Allen - if either of these solutions work for you, it would be useful if you accepted an answer. That way, people know if there was a solution that worked in your case.

Comment: You sir, are my hero.  I've been working at this since last Monday, but could not for the life of me either figure out a way or even search for a way to accomplish this.  The first solution is what I needed, but adding `.parent()` to the show and hide lines.  I cannot begin to thank you enough for this!

Comment: Hey, no problem. I've been there too. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to add a small sub-question, and didn't submit a new question because I find it highly relevant to this current question (most people who stumble upon this would probably like to know).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to hide all posts with class "post_entry", then show only those which have all selected categories:

```
$(".post_entry").hide().filter(".category1.category2.categoryN").show();
```

jquery filter() with classes listed with no spaces gives an intersection of the selected items; if you want union (the items with at least one category), use filter with `".category1, .category2, .categoryN"`

Comment: I think this would work if I combine it with @g_thom's answer.  I was basically trying to think of a way to use the classes to filter out the post based on a child `div`'s classes.  I think `filter` might be a more efficient way, but @g_thom provides a more complete solution based on my needs. Thanks for the information!